# How to add Keyboard Shortcuts to an ICommand object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, wcf-binding

I have an ICommand property that looks like this:

```
private ICommand autoHideCommand;
public ICommand AutoHideCommand
{
   get { return autoHideCommand; }
   set
   {
      if (!object.Equals(autoHideCommand, value))
      {
         autoHideCommand = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("AutoHideCommand");
      }
   }
}
```

The actual class under the command can be found [here](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94905#1742961).  It is a fairly basic ICommand implementation.

I would really like to add some keyboard input bindings to this command.  But the actual implementation does not support it and neither does ICommand.

Does anyone have an example on how I can add keyboard bindings in this scenario?  (Is it even possible?)

NOTE: I need to do this in C# code (not XAML).  That is because my window is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

The command implementation doesn't need to know what called it (a button or a keyboard shortcut, etc).

When you create your `Window`, you need to create a `CommandBinding` and add it to the Window's [`CommandBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.commandbindings.aspx).  This will route the keyboard shortcut to your `ICommand`.